# Spring-Cloud-Stream Kafka Azure - Unexpected error code 13 while fetching data

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka

I'm developing a SpringBoot app dockerized.
The docker images are microservices and one of these communicate with Azure Event Hub.

Some of my properties:

> spring-boot -> **2.0.7.RELEASE**
>
> spring-cloud.version -> **Finchley.SR2**

I've created a topic in Azure(with **Kafka enabled**).

I've follow some simple guide to set up my microservice and everything works fine.

```
@EnableBinding({Processor.class})
public class EventService {
    ...
    @Autowired private Processor ehProcessor;
    ...
    public void send(String event) {

        Message<String> message = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(event)
                .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build();

        boolean send = ehProcessor.output().send(message, 5000L);

        if (!send) {

            log.error("Event NOT sent", event);
        }
    }

    ...

    @StreamListener(target = Processor.INPUT)
    public void receive(String event) {

        handle(event);
    }
}
```

For an entire month everything goes fine but in the last two days the microservice stucks because a continuous stacktrace is filling all my disc (a solution was to set up a docker log rotation).

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected error code 13 while fetching data
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseCompletedFetch(Fetcher.java:891) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:528) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1154) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1111) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:699) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

I'm talking about 8/9 log messsage in 1 ms.

Looking inside the **org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.Errors** class
the error is related to:

> NETWORK_EXCEPTION(13, "The server disconnected before a response was
> received."

I'm not able to reproduce programmatically this error.
I don't understand why when the first error is arised the log will start and no stop in infinite loop. I need to stop the docker container and sometimes the container will not stop.
The only solution is to remove the container and recreate again.

**UPDATE**

I've open an issue on github [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/issues/31). I've already received a response and they are starting to investigate on it.

**UPDATE**

The problem has been fixed.

> When they changed an UnknownServerException to a NetworkException,
> Spring Boot started getting stuck in the retry loop.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this using same code but without docker? Just trying to see if it is network related within the docker context

Comment: I've try to run the standalone spring boot  app without docker but cannot reproduce it. I've try to disable the network card during application run so I've received the connection error but all seems to be managed in the right way and the system is not collapsing that way but is stable

Comment: From what you have described it seems like the error is specific to how Docker is getting network access, and I am guessing you are using AKS in this case. You can actually file a support ticket with Azure to get additional help from the AKS support.

Comment: With AKS are you referring to this: https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/services/kubernetes-service/ ? Do you know any working guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has confirm in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53938612/582421) that,

There was a recent change where an instance of UnknownServerException was changed to a NetworkException.

Issue details are here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/issues - with your namespace info. Thanks!