# Unexpected error code 13 while fetching data Spring-Cloud-Stream Kafka Azure event hub -

Tags: azure, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, azure-eventhub

It was working fine suddenly this issue popup since 18th Dec, could not find any clue, what suddenly this exception is coming continuously after 6 month working fine.

I am not able to reproduce in local standalone and but it comes in The docker images with **micro-services** and one of these communicate with **Azure even hub**.

I have search and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872902/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-azure-unexpected-error-code-13-while-fetching-data). In this post also reported same issue what i am facing but could not find any resolution or clue so I am posting this question.

Please refer below stacktrace:

```
 Error while processing: null 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected error code 13 while fetching data 
 at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseCompletedFetch(Fetcher.java:891) 
 at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:528) 
 at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1154) 
 at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1111) 
 at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:699) 
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

If any one any clue please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a recent change where an instance of UnknownServerException was changed to a NetworkException - this unintentionally changed consumer client retry behavior.  File an issue here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/issues - with your namespace info.  Thanks!